# Asymptotic approximation of the Bessel integral

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

I wonder what would be the asymptotic behaviour of $Re \int_0^{\infty}\,J_0(ks)e^{-i\sqrt{\alpha k}t}kdk$ for $s,\alpha$ large enough. $J_0$ is the Bessel function of zeroth order.

I feel it is strange problem. $f(x)$ grows as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

$f(k) = J_0(kr)k$ and $J_0 \sim k^{-1/2}$,  so $f(k) \sim k^{1/2}$.

From other hand,
$J_0 \sim \cos(ks) e^{-i \sqrt{\alpha k} t}$ product of two functions oscillating with different frequencies could give zero result, but $\int |f(k)| dk  = \infty$.

Comment: Integral does not converge. You sure you have the right function?

Comment: Mathematica gives for the zeroth order Hankel transform of $e^{-it\sqrt{\alpha k}}$ a Meijier G function $\frac{1}{s^2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi^3}}G^{3,1}_{3,1}\left( \left(\frac{\alpha t^2}{8s}\right)^2 \bigg| \matrix{0 &  \\1/2 & /4 &3/4}\right)$